# Parent field readonly while linking excel to ADO

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have linked ms excel to ADO using the plugin and I'm able to everything except for updation of parent story ID field ( column) . That field for me is coming as read only. The message I get is "TF84013: you cannot modify a field that is read-only or a work item that restricts updates to valid users based on current conditions". What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

The Parent-Child link types are supported by the Tree list. I tested with tree list type and the parent field is modifiable.

[image]

You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#add-a-hierarchy-of-linked-work-items).

Comment: I'm not referring to id but parent field. I understand ID is auto generated but I want to attach my user story to a parent feature

Comment: Are you using the tree hierarchy? Note that only the Parent-Child link types are supported by the [Tree list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#add-a-hierarchy-of-linked-work-items).

Comment: Add tree level option is greyed out. Here is the screenshot. Looking forward to hearing form you https://ibb.co/p1JNSXZ

Comment: From your screenshots, you are not using [Parent-Child link types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUkmZ.png). Only the Parent-Child link types are supported by the Tree list.